# Linux /etc/group and /etc/passwd don't match?

Tags: linux

I have a group named "www" (GID=997), which has users *mydata*, *adb* and *root*.

If I use `$groups mydata` or `$groups adb`, it shows `mydata : www`. Also in **/etc/passwd** file, I can see `mydata:x:2001:997:` and `adb:x:2003:997:`.

But in **/etc/group** file, it show `www:!:997:root`.

First, I don't understand why this www group only shows the user *root*, not followed by other users in this group. I think in the group file there should be something like `www:!:997:root,mydata,adb`

Second, what does "!" mean here? I know that if it shows **x** (`www:x:997:...`) then it means the group has a password. But I can't find out the explanation for "**!**" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each user has one primary group, and can have multiple secondary groups.

The primary group is the one whichs group id is in the `passwd` file, in the `group` file you have the information to which secondary groups the user belongs. It would be possible to add the user's primary group to it's seccondary groups, but that's redundant.

The `!` in the groups file is used to indicate that the group has no password set for grouplogin. You can find that informatoin in the manpage for [`gshadow`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gshadow), as it is more common to have an `x` in the password field in the groups file, indicating that the password information should be taken from `/etc/gshadow` instead.